# How do I prove that quadratic integers can be intepreted as this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $B,C$ be integers.

Set $\mathscr{A}=\{w\in\mathbb{C}: w^2+Bw+C=0\}$.

Set $\mathscr{B}=\{\sqrt{D}: D\equiv 0,2,3 \pmod 4\}\cup \{\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}: D\equiv 1 \pmod 4\}$.

How do I prove that $\mathscr{A}=\mathscr{B}$?

Actually, they may not be equal, but I'm guessing since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2}]$ are called quadratic integer rings. If not, why are they called so?

I know the Legendre symbol and related basic number theoretic tools, but I don't have an idea how to prove this.. Thank you in advance

Comment: Notice the use of \pmod in my edit. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Something in your description is incorrect; note that setting $B=0$, $C=-5$ yields a $w=\sqrt{5}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ which isn't in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Done. I changed (mod 4), rendered as $(mod 4)$, to \pmod 4, rendered as $\pmod 4$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thank you :)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Then what would be the correct statement..? And I think you have a typo. You may mean C=-25

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You should take the ring generated by the integers along with $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: PS: when using \pmod followed by more than one character, one needs braces, thus: \pmod{42} is rendered as $\pmod{42}$, whereas \pmod42 is rendered as $\pmod42$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$ be a field extension. We say that $k \in K$ is an integer in $K$ if $k$ is the root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. When $K = \mathbb{Q}$, this gives you the familiar integers.

When $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ (one can assume $d$ is square-free), then the integers by the definition above are precisely that mentioned in the question. This follows from nothing more than elementary number theory and is a pleasurable exercise.

Note that if $w$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients, then $\mathbb{Q}[w]$ is a quadratic extension. All quadratic extensions are of the form $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ by completing the square. It follows that $\mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{A}] = \mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{B}]$, although $\mathscr{A} \neq \mathscr{B}$ as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}[\mathscr{A}]$, do you mean the subring of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by $\mathbb{Z}\cup \mathscr{A}$? Or do you mean that for each $w\in \mathscr{A}$, there exists $x\in \mathscr{B}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}[w]=\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: The former. In general, $R[\{x_i\}]$ is the ring generated by $R$ and $\{x_i\}$.